# failed to have geom_bar dodge on Shiny

Tags: r, database, shiny, analysis

Hi I have a question related to ggplot geom_bar(position dodge) and shiny.

my Shiny app page doesn't show bars within various groups, but only one bar shows the number of count of the totol models in my file.

Then I try to run a test in my console, I found that

> x = (   ) can not be  "Model"(a character) but has to be Model(no
>   showed as character.

The code below worked:

```
 ggplot(data = m_epiq_original) + 
        geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Model, fill = Date), position = "dodge")
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
 ggplot(data = m_epiq_original) + 
        geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = "Model", fill = "Date"), position = "dodge")
```

The difference is that I use "Model" and "Date".

And since I'm using Shiny, the my selectInput is like

```
c("Model", "Date")
```

, so that other code can work. and actually they work well.

but I don't understand why geom_bar dodge doesn't recognize in this way, and my shiny web page only shows me a giany pink bar that has the count of 199, which is the count of the total number of rows in my file. It doesn't read my x= and fill = and doesn't do the grouping and counting for each.

Hopefully my question is clear. I'm new so please let me know if you  need any clarifications. Thanks!

Comment: There is an `aes_string` function in ggplot which may work. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/1.0.0/topics/aes_string

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works out!!! Appreciate!:)

Comment: could consider answering your own question and provide a reproducible example and solution